# assign local value within lambda expressiom

Tags: java, javafx, lambda

I'm Trying to get the file path using lambda expression but I am facing issue cause lambda refuse to assign the value. The lambda code:

```
String moviePoster_string="";
choosePoster_Button.setOnAction(
    e -> {
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
            new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("All Images", "*.jpg","*.png")
        );
        File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
        moviePoster_string = file.getPath();
    }
);
```

I got this error

> error: local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be
>   final or effectively final

I'm Not using foreach I'm using lambda expression within the javafx code

Comment: I think that the error message can not get MORE descriptive then this.

Comment: You can try to use an `AtomicReference<String>` rather than use a simple `String` variable. Note that the filechooser won't block the thread, though, so if you're using that value in a line of code immediately following the lambda, it'll have issues. Look into a `CountDownLatch` for that issue.

Comment: @Eugene I know and it's clear. Obviously the question is how to get the path then.

Comment: What good would that do anyways? The scope of the method containing that code should be left long before the user gets a change to click the button and select a file...

Comment: Not sure if it works, but you can try using Stringbuilder moviePoster and append(file.getPath()). The compiler adds this to the variable. Not good for multithreading

Comment: @MrRizk, If you want to get the file path then simply return from the lambda expression 
instead of assigning it to some variable.

Comment: @sunitSingh in lambda??  I used lambda in the button function so how do I return string.